# Docker-compose variable-substitution mandatory variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, yaml, variable-substitution

I have a docker-compose file that uses variable substitution for some secrets and I want to get an error if they are not supplied or empty, for this purpose I have tried this:

```
environment:
  - >-
    JAVA_OPTS=
    -DMYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:?MYSQL_USER_NOT_SET}
    -DMYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:?MYSQL_PASSWORD_NOT_SET}
    -DMYSQL_URL=db:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE:?MYSQL_DATABASE_NOT_SET}
```

However, it gives me the error:

> ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "myservice": "JAVA_OPTS= -DMYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER:?MYSQL_USER_NOT_SET}...

According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution this should work since it has this snippet:

> Similarly, the following syntax allows you to specify mandatory
>   variables:
>
> ${VARIABLE:?err} exits with an error message containing err if
>   VARIABLE is unset or empty in the environment. ${VARIABLE?err} exits
>   with an error message containing err if VARIABLE is unset in the
>   environment.

I also have `version: "3.4"` in my docker-compose so that shouldn't be the issue.

Already tried it with just `${MY_VAR?MY_ERROR}` but it didn't work either.
I have even gone as far as to look at the source code but found nothing helpful.

### EDIT :

I tried to make a minimum size reproduction:

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  hello:
    image: hello-world
    environment:
      - TEST=${TEST?err}
```

`docker-compose up`

> ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "hello": "TEST=${TEST?err}

Comment: Using `${MY_VAR?MY_ERROR}` works for me and gives me the error `ERROR: Missing mandatory value for "environment" option in service "app": MY_ERROR`. Also your `environment` key works with the expected error message (not the interpolation one you get).

Comment: Another thing to note. You must use "docker-compose" and not "docker compose". I guess the "compose" subcommand has not yet reached feature parity for this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on your docker-compose version.

With docker-compose `1.17.1` you will get
`ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "my-service": ...`
if you use `${TEST?"My error message"}` but with
e.g. docker-compose `1.29.2` it works as expected
`ERROR: Missing mandatory value for "environment" option interpolating ... in service "my-service": "My error message"`